# Is it possible to update records in one SELECT with the detail totals from another file

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, correlated-subquery

I have a trigger created on an invoice header file. It creates a PPAY table row, however the total amount is not known at the time of the trigger. The amount needed to populate the PPAY amount is the total of all the associated invoice detail records (which are not written out at the time of the header insert trigger).

The Header record insert trigger creates a PPAY record with a NULL amount. The total amounts are to be gathered from the MRRECVD table, where the CONTROL# of both the PPAY and MRRECVD have to match.

The following does not work:

```
-- Add the amount to the PPAY items in one sentence
UPDATE [PositivePay].[dbo].[PPAY] 
    SET AMOUNT = (
        SELECT SUM(DETAIL_AMOUNT) 
        FROM [TMP].[dbo].[MRRECVD] d
        WHERE d.CONTROL = CONTROL
        GROUP BY d.CONTROL
        )
WHERE AMOUNT IS NULL
```

I get this error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My understanding is that to get around that, I should reduce my subquery so that it only returns one result, which is the whole idea of SUM().

I should also mention that the common factor between the PPAY and MRRECVD tables is the CONTROL column, whereas there can be multiple rows in the PPAY table differentiated by a CONTROL_SEQ (1,2,3,etc).

Is this even possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

Including `GROUP BY d.CONTROL` is not necessary although I cannot see why it would give you more than one value because you are supposed to only have one type of control value given your where clause.

Try removing the GROUP BY clause to see if you get a single sum value.

Comment: Yeah, why is there more than one group? Maybe SQL Server's crazy matching of trailing whitespace?

Comment: I have no idea, but the best way to check it is to run: SELECT *
        FROM [TMP].[dbo].[MRRECVD] d
        WHERE d.CONTROL = CONTROL
        GROUP BY d.CONTROL

Comment: You cannot remove the GROUP BY because SQL requires it when you use an aggregate, in this case SUM() (which I knew before I posted the question):  
<br>

    Column 'TMP.dbo.MRRECVD.CONTROL' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.  
<br>

-- It should be noted that the inner select works great, returning one result per output line if the outer statement is a SELECT rather than an UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

It works! It should be stressed that the GROUP BY clause is necessary because of the aggregate SUM()

```
UPDATE p
    SET p.AMOUNT = d.sum_amt
FROM [PositivePay].[dbo].[PPAY] p
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  CONTROL, sum(d.DETAIL_AMOUNT) as sum_amt
        FROM [TMP].[dbo].[MRRECVD] d
        GROUP BY CONTROL
    ) AS d
    ON p.CONTROL = d.CONTROL
WHERE p.AMOUNT IS NULL
```